# How to delete all dead/broken shortcuts on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts

Is there a method or tool that can delete all dead/broken shortcuts on a Windows 7 64bit system?

Comment: I'm developing a Java program called *MyShell* in which I'm adding commands every now and then, and for this particular case I've implemented a command `clean shortcuts <path>` that cleans all **dead/broken** shortcuts or symbolic links. You can get the *jar* file at https://github.com/dinomario10/MyShell under *Releases*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While wysiwyg already answered with a pretty good general cleaner tool that may do this as well, I think the real answer might be a spesific tool that does this. Here are two such:

**Fix Shortcuts** from Puran Software is a free utility that can help you find and fix or delete broken shortcuts on your computer http://www.puransoftware.com/Fix-Shortcuts.html

**Broken Shortcut Fixer** scans your Windows computer for broken shortcuts and automatically repairs any shortcuts that it can find using the Windows link resolve method http://www.brokenshortcutfixer.com/

Answer (score 1):

I believe CCleaner has this feature.

http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

You can download a portable version here if you wish:
http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds

> CCleaner is a small, effective utility for computers running Microsoft
>   Windows that cleans out the 'junk' that accumulates over time:
>   temporary files, **broken shortcuts**, and other problems.

Comment: Yes it does. But only for Desktop and Start Menu shortcuts.